# How to filter .csv file into columns on GO

Tags: csv, file, go

I am trying to filter a .csv file to only include 2 columns that will be specified by the user. My current code can only filter the .csv file to one column (but when I write to a .csv file, the results are in a row instead of a column) . Any ideas on how to filter the two columns and write the results in a single column on Go? Seems

In addition, is there any way I can write the data as a column instead of a row?

```
import (
    "encoding/csv"
    "fmt"
    "io"
    "log"
    "os"
)
func main() {
        file, err := os.Open("sample.csv")
        checkError(err)

        reader := csv.NewReader(file)
        _, err = reader.Read() //Skips header
        checkError(err)
        results := make([]string, 0)

        for {
            row, err := reader.Read()
            if err == io.EOF {
                break
            }
            if err != nil {
                log.Fatal(err)
            }
            //fmt.Println(row[columnNum])
            results = append(results, row[columnNum])

        }
        fmt.Print(results)

        //File creation
        f, err := os.Create("results.csv")
        checkError(err)
        defer f.Close()

        w := csv.NewWriter(f)
        err = w.Write(results)
        checkError(err)
        w.Flush()
}
```

Comment: Can you explain a little more about what you expect to happen? For example, I'm not sure what you mean by "filter the two columns and write the results in a single column" - can you provide a minimal sample input (`sample.csv`) along with actual and expected outputs (`results.csv`)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> ...is there any way I can write the data as a column instead of a row?

You're only writing a single column. You call `w.Write` once, which [writes a single record to the CSV](https://golang.org/pkg/encoding/csv/#Writer.Write). If you write once per consumed row, you'll get multiple rows. Notice that you're calling read `Read` many times and `Write` once.

> Any ideas on how to filter the two columns and write the results in a single column on Go?

To get two columns, you just need to access both - I see one access to each row right now (`row[columnNum]`), so you'll just need a second. Combined with my previous point, I think the main problem is that you're missing that CSVs are two dimensional but you're only storing a single dimensional array.

I'm not sure what you mean by "write to a single column" - maybe you want to double the length of the CSV, or maybe you want to somehow merge two columns?

In either case, I'd suggest restructuring your code to avoid building up the intermediate `results` array, and instead write directly after reading. This will be more performant and more directly maps from the old format to the new one.

```golang
    file, err := os.Open("sample.csv")
    checkError(err)

    reader := csv.NewReader(file)
    _, err = reader.Read() // Skips header
    checkError(err)

    // Create the file and writer immediately
    f, err := os.Create("results.csv")
    checkError(err)
    defer f.Close()

    w := csv.NewWriter(f)

    for {
        row, err := reader.Read()
        if err == io.EOF {
            break
        }
        if err != nil {
            log.Fatal(err)
        }
        // here - each row is written to the new CSV writer
        err = w.Write([]string{row[columnNum]})

        // an example of writing two columns to each row
        // err = w.Write([]string{row[columnNum1], row[columnNum2]})

        // an example of merging two rows
        // err = w.Write([]string{fmt.Sprintf("%s - %s", row[columnNum1], row[columnNum2])})

        checkError(err)
    }

    w.Flush()
```